# Looping multiple pdf and converting to multiple excel using R programming

Tags: r, excel, pdf, lapply

I have few PDF files in a folder. I am performing certain operations and converting them into excel. Below is the code,

```
init <- dir(path = "C:/Users/sankirtanmoturi/Desktop/rloop", pattern = "\\.pdf$", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
trans <- function(file){
      try <- pdf_text(file)
      try1 <- unlist(str_split(try,"[\\r\\n]+"))
      try2 <- str_split_fixed(str_trim(try1), "\\s{1,}, 20")
      write.xlsx(try2, sub("\\.xlsx$", "-UP.xlsx", file))
 }
lapply(init, trans)
```

I am getting the below error

**Error in identical(n, Inf) : argument "n" is missing, with no default**

I figured out that, there's problem with str_split or str_split_fixed.
But if I am not trying to loop and try for a single file, It is converting successfully

Please help me to run this for all pdf files in a folder

Comment: you mis-placed the quotes ". replace you code for this line `try2 <- str_split_fixed(str_trim(try1), "\\s{1,}", 20)`

Comment: After doing the changes I am getting new error **Error in createWorkbook(type = ext) : Unknown format pdf**

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly typos in your question. The below code should work:

```
init <- dir(path = "C:/Users/sankirtanmoturi/Desktop/rloop", pattern = "\\.pdf$", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
trans <- function(file){
  try <- pdf_text(file)
  try1 <- unlist(str_split(try,"[\\r\\n]+"))
  try2 <- str_split_fixed(str_trim(try1), "\\s{1,}", 20)
  write.xlsx(try2, sub("\\.pdf$", "-UP.xlsx", file))
}
lapply(init, trans)
```